# how to call mysql update query using onclick function

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stu WHERE receiver='DM4'"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ptype'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['source'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['letterno'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['descrip'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['receiver'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='vex.php?uid={$row['letterno']}'  id='id' onClick='addfavourite()'>.{$row['title']}.</a></td>";
 //echo "<td><a href='update.php?id={$row['id']}'>Update</a></td>";
echo"<td><img style='width:100px;higth:150px;' src='upload/{$row[image]}'></td>";
addfavourite();
echo addfavourite();
function addfavourite() {
 $ide=$_GET['uid'];
 //echo $ide;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stu WHERE letterno = '$ide'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row){
$newfav = "UPDATE stu SET open = 1 WHERE letterno = '$ide'";     
$createfav = mysql_query($newfav);}
else{
$newfav = "UPDATE stu SET open = 0 WHERE letterno = '$ide'";   
$createfav = mysql_query($newfav);}
}

}
echo $ide;


?>
```

This is my error code.In this code,there is a fault with mysql query statement.it is not supported with the databse. but onclick() function is working.

Comment: what is the error message you receive?

Comment: Use ajax to call your update query. Your above code is not proper, you need to rework the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly execute a PHP function from a JavaScript event. Simply, cannot mix server side and client side logic but you can make two of them interact with each other.

In this case, you can create a JavaScript function which sends an AJAX request to a PHP page on your server containing the code of `addfavourite()`.

---

#### A Demo

I haven't tested the code below but assuming that your code logic and rest stuff is correct, this might just work

`demo.php`

```
<script>
    function addfavourite(uid){
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "addfavourite.php"; // URL of your PHP file
        var vars = "uid="+uid;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
        }
        // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
</script>

<?php
    include_once("db.php");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stu WHERE receiver='DM4'");
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ptype'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['source'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['letterno'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['descrip'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['receiver'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='#'  id='id' onClick='addfavourite({$row['letterno']})'>.{$row['title']}.</a></td>";
        echo"<td><img style='width:100px;higth:150px;' src='upload/{$row[image]}'></td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
<div id='status'></div>
```

`addfavourite.php`

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['uid'])) {
        $ide = $_POST['uid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM stu WHERE letterno = '$ide'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row) {
            $newfav = "UPDATE stu SET open = 1 WHERE letterno = '$ide'";
            $createfav = mysql_query($newfav);
        } else {
            $newfav = "UPDATE stu SET open = 0 WHERE letterno = '$ide'";
            $createfav = mysql_query($newfav);
        }
        if ($createfav) {
            echo "<script>alert('Added to favourite successfully...')";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong...')";
        }
    }else{
        echo "POST variable not set!";
    }
?>
```

#### Some notes

- You should use mysqli insted of mysql functions as it is deprecated and no longer supported
- This here is a good video tutorial on AJAX https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Ajax-Post-to-PHP-File-XMLHttpRequest-Object-Return-Data-Tutorial

Comment: i don't know how to do that.can you help me

Comment: your link is not supported.i have massage

Comment: Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Comment: The link is correct. Try copy/pasting it into the URL bar.